# Add menu options in a running powershell script

Tags: powershell, ssh, scripting, menu, powershell-ise

I am using a PowerShell script with an interactive console menu that uses functions in the switch part. looks like this:

```
function startmenu {
    do {
        [int]$selection = 0
        while ($selection-lt 1 -or $selection-gt 5){
            Write-Host "1. Search"
            write-host "2. Change"
            Write-Host "3. do stuff"
            write-host "4. Clear Screen"
            write-host "5. Exit"

            [int]$selection= read-host "choose one option"
            switch ($selection) {
                1{find}
                2{change}
                3{dostuff}
                4{cls}
                5{exit}
            }
        }
    }
    while ($selection -ne 4)}
```

Right now I am trying to build a new script with a similar menu for ssh connections. 
Since PowerShell has its own ssh client. 
Sometimes you have to add new servers to your server list, 
like putty or something. So I want to add new options to my menu while running the script. 
maybe with a function "add a new server to list". 
But I have no idea how to realize this. 
my colleagues would use this scrip as well and they may have other servers so the menu has to be some kind of 
dynamic for every user of it.
Everyone should build their own list without touching the script.

Is there any possible way? my PowerShell knowledge is pretty basic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To have a console menu where users can add options, perhaps the following will give you an idea of how you could do that:

```
function Show-Menu {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [string[]]$options = @('FileZilla', 'Posh-SSH PowerShell', 'WinSCP','PuTTY')
    )
    # store the options in a List object for easy addition
    $list = [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]::new()
    $list.AddRange($options)

    # now start an endless loop for the menu handling
    while ($true) { 
        Clear-Host
        # loop through the options list and build the menu
        Write-Host "`r`nPlease choose from the list below.`r`n"
        $index = 1
        $list.Sort()
        $list | ForEach-Object { Write-Host ("{0}.`t{1}" -f $index++, $_ )}
        Write-Host "`r`nN.`tAdd a new item to the list"
        Write-Host "Q.`tQuit"

        $selection = Read-Host "`r`nEnter Option"

        switch ($selection) {
            {$_ -like 'N*' } {
                # the user want to add a new item to the menu
                $item = (Read-Host "Please add a new item").Trim()
                if (![string]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($item) -and $list -notcontains $item) {
                    Write-Host "Adding new item '$item'.." -ForegroundColor Yellow
                    $list.Add($item)
                }
            }
            {$_ -like 'Q*' } { 
                # if the user presses 'Q', exit the function
                return 
            } 
            default {
                # test if a valid numeric input in range has been given
                if ([int]::TryParse($selection, [ref]$index)) {
                    if ($index -gt 0 -and $index -le $list.Count) {
                        # do whatever you need to perform
                        $selection = $list[$index - 1]  # this gives you the text of the selected item

                        # for demo, just output on screen what option was selected
                        Write-Host "Building connection using $selection" -ForegroundColor Green
                        # return the selection made to the calling script
                        return $selection
                    }
                    else {
                        Write-Host "Please enter a valid option from the menu" -ForegroundColor Red
                    }
                }
                else {
                    Write-Host "Please enter a valid option from the menu" -ForegroundColor Red
                }
            }
        }

        # add a little pause and start over again
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
    }
}

# call the function
$choice = Show-Menu
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I can use this! But is there a way to configure every entry i add in the list? i want to use this script only for ssh sessions with different names, ip addresses and usernames, which need to be configured differently in every entry. i hope my explaination is understandable.. so if i add a new entry eg. netapp with 192.168.12.18 and a username it should be saved for every time i open this script again. or maybe i have to write a config file like a txt file where i save the changes and load it every time i open the script so connect to my ssh hosts.

Comment: Thanks for your information. i will look it up. ive accepted the answer!